# UPDATE records of a table by checking the information from other three tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've following tables:

```
wi_individiual_g(ind_id, ind_name, ...)
wi_training(trn_id, trn_name, ...)
wi_group(grp_id, grp_name, ...)
```

Here, a group can be formed by individuals that are placed under:

```
wi_indv_org(ind_id, grp_id, is_deleted)
```

A training can be provided to a group or individuals. That is, a training can consists multiple group(s) and other individuals separately(can also be from other groups which are not the part of training). For this, I've created two tables:

```
wi_trn_org(trn_id, grp_id, is_deleted)
wi_indv_training(ind_id,trn_id,is_deleted)
```

In wi_indv_training, the individuals are from group(s) that are in training or are from anonymous group as mentioned above. After entering data more than 200K, I've added a column indv_source in wi_indv_training. As

```
wi_indv_training(ind_id,trn_id,indv_source, is_deleted)
```

This column checks if the individual is from a group or anonymous group. If the individual is from group than it is flagged as GROUP otherwise it is flagged as Individual.
This concept is working for data that are newly entered. 
But I need to update the previous data 200K to check if the individuals involved in training are GROUP sourced or INDIVIDUAL Sourced. To solve this problem I've written this PHP code but its taking more than 15 minutes to execute.

```
$trn=$this->db->pdoQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(trn_id) AS trn_id FROM wi_indv_training WHERE is_deleted=0")->results();
        foreach ($trn as $key => $value) {
            $trn_id=$value['trn_id'];
            $grp=$this->db->pdoQuery("UPDATE wi_indv_training SET indv_source='Group' 
                WHERE EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT(wi_indv_org.ind_id) FROM wi_indv_org 
                    INNER JOIN wi_trn_org ON wi_indv_org.grp_id=wi_trn_org.grp_id AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0 
                    AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0
                    AND wi_trn_org.trn_id=$trn_id
                ) 
                AND ind_id IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT(wi_indv_org.ind_id) FROM wi_indv_org 
                    INNER JOIN wi_trn_org ON wi_indv_org.grp_id=wi_trn_org.grp_id AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0 
                    AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0
                    AND wi_trn_org.trn_id=$trn_id
                );UPDATE wi_indv_training SET indv_source='Individual' WHERE trn_id=$trn_id AND ind_id NOT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT(wi_indv_org.ind_id) FROM wi_indv_org 
                    INNER JOIN wi_trn_org ON wi_indv_org.grp_id=wi_trn_org.grp_id AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0 
                    AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0
                    AND wi_trn_org.trn_id=$trn_id
                )");
        }
```

The requirement in SQL is;

```
Step 1) To select a training. 
Step 2) Search for groups that are involved in training. 
Step 3) Search for individuals that are in groups provided by above step
Step 4) Update the table wi_indv_training records as indv_source='Group' if records found for that training
Step 5) Update all remaining records as indv_source='Individual' for provided training.
```

I need a solution that executes fast. I would be glad if someone help me. Thank you!

Comment: If it's a one time thing, why does it matter that it's slow?

Comment: I would recommend removing the DISTINCT clause. It is not serving any purpose. Try getting the explain for the query after that and post it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: While executing from PHP, its running over maximum script runtime. If the same query can be executed in MySQL using any techniques like looping in SQL, the solution would be appreciable.

Comment: DISTINCT is fetching the unique training id since the table wi_indv_training might have same training id.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two queries instead of your for-loop:

```
UPDATE wi_indv_training
    INNER JOIN wi_indv_org ON
        wi_indv_training.is_deleted=0
        AND wi_indv_org.trn_id=wi_indv_training.trn_id
    INNER JOIN wi_trn_org ON
        wi_indv_org.grp_id=wi_trn_org.grp_id
        AND wi_trn_org.is_deleted=0
        AND wi_trn_org.trn_id=wi_indv_training.trn_id
    SET
        wi_indv_training.indv_source = 'Group';

UPDATE wi_indv_training
    SET
        wi_indv_training.indv_source='Individual'
    WHERE
        AND wi_indv_training.is_deleted=0
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT ind_id
            FROM wi_indv_org
            WHERE
                wi_indv_org.trn_id = wi_indv_training.trn_id
                AND wi_indv_org.ind_id=wi_indv_training.ind_id
            LIMIT 1
        );
```

As much as possible, avoid subqueries as it will slow down your query.
If you can't avoid it, at least make the subquery fast by limiting the number of rows it returns.

Your code essentially runs:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT trn_id) FROM wi_indv_training
```

queries! If you have 200k rows in wi_indv_training table, it means you're running 200k queries which explains why it is so slow.

Comment: As per the table I've provided, There can have multiple groups that can be assigned to a training. This means same group can be assigned to other training as well. And the individuals from other groups can also be assigned to the training. The above mentioned solution would update all the matching records that could consits all training and all groups. This would be a error for the specific training that has particular group or individual.